# Exclude Numbers in pattern match

Tags: java, regex, numbers

I am using this piece of code to test if the pattern matches.
It should throw an error if the input includes Numbers, extra space, special characters. (If the pattern doesn't match.)

For that I have written the below code.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z{',-}]");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher("1xyz");
```

In output, I am getting `There is a  no special character in my string for first name`.
In pattern match I have only given match iff we have letters, `-,'` as special characters, but it's going take numbers also as acceptance not sure why.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should throw an error if the input includes Numbers, extra space,
> special characters.

...

> In pattern match I have only given match iff we have letters, -,' as
> special characters,

You can do it the other way round i.e. use the pattern, `[0-9-,'\s]` which means a digit or `-` or `,` or `'` or a whitespace character.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test-1
        checkName("1xyz");

        // Test-2
        checkName("xyz");

        // Test-3
        checkName("Hello World");
    }

    static void checkName(String name) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9-,'\\s]");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(name);
        if (match.find()) {
            System.out.println("There is a digit, whitespace or a special character in the name.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The name is valid.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
There is a digit, whitespace or a special character in the name.
The name is valid.
There is a digit, whitespace or a special character in the name.
```

### Update (based on OP's comment):

If you want to mark the first name invalid if it has any of the following

1. a digit
2. a [punctuation/special character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  from !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~
3. a whitespace character

you should use the regex, `[0-9\p{Punct}\s]`

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "1xyz", "xyz", "Hello World", "He^llo", "James@Bond" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            checkFirstName(s);
        }

    }

    static void checkFirstName(String name) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9\\p{Punct}\\s]");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(name);
        if (match.find()) {
            System.out.println(name + " is not a valid first name.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " is a valid first name.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1xyz is not a valid first name.
xyz is a valid first name.
Hello World is not a valid first name.
He^llo is not a valid first name.
James@Bond is not a valid first name.
```

### Yet another update (based on OP's further comments):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "1xyz", "xyz", "Hello World", "He^llo", "James@Bond", "L'Oreal", "sai-praveena",
                "sai-praveena-m", "O'ClockL'Oreal" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            checkFirstName(s);
        }

    }

    static void checkFirstName(String name) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}]+[-']?[\\p{L}]+");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(name);
        if (!match.matches()) {
            System.out.println(name + " is not a valid first name.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " is a valid first name.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1xyz is not a valid first name.
xyz is a valid first name.
Hello World is not a valid first name.
He^llo is not a valid first name.
James@Bond is not a valid first name.
L'Oreal is a valid first name.
sai-praveena is a valid first name.
sai-praveena-m is not a valid first name.
O'ClockL'Oreal is not a valid first name.
```

The regex, `[\p{L}]+[-']?[\p{L}]+` means one of more letters (i.e. `[\p{L}]+`) followed by an optional `-` or `'` which is in turn followed by one or more letters.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine by placing but as per mentioned above it should accept only '  ' and - but its going to accept @ and ^

Comment: @saipraveena - Great! Your question was specific to digits, whitespace and one of `-,'` and therefore I had put only these things in my answer. Based on your comment, I have posted an update which should fulfil your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine by placing the below piece                                                           
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^{',-}a-zA-Z[0-9-]]");                                                   
 but as per mentioned above it should accept only ' and - but its going to accept @ and ^ but not accepting hypen(-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Need to accept : A to Z,a to z, hypen(-) apostrophe('). Should not accept -  Numbers,special characters except - and ' space

Comment: ya only one hypen and one apostrophe

Comment: Hi, I have tried with this code piece                                                                                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9\\p{Punct}\\s&&[^',-]]");                                                       finally it worked for me for my validations. its not going to accept 0-9 numbers and punctuations except ' and -. Thanks a lot

Comment: But it is also accepting the words which have multiple hypens and apostrophes.. can u help me to this

Comment: @saipraveena - Based on your comments, I've posted yet another update. I hope, it fulfils your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Its accepting more than one hypen and apostrophe. I need to accept when its occured only once. Can you help me on this                                                                                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9\\p{Punct}\\s&&[^',-]]");                                                 it should not accept if this is the input                                                               
 Matcher match = pattern.matcher("Sm't'h");                                                                   Matcher match = pattern.matcher("Sm'h"); only this is acceptable

Comment: @saipraveena - No, the pattern in my answer is accepting only one hyphen or apostrophe e.g. it outputs `sai-praveena-m is not a valid first name.` and `O'ClockL'Oreal is not a valid first name.` Check the last update (under the heading, **Yet another update**)